# Issue with drawContours OpenCV c++

Tags: opencv, contour

I have a code in python and I am porting it to c++. I am getting a weird issue with `drawContours` function in OpenCV c++.

```
self.contours[i] = cv2.convexHull(self.contours[i])
cv2.drawContours(self.segments[object], [self.contours[i]], 0, 255, -1)
```

this is the function call in python and the value -1 for the thickness parameter is used for filling the contour and the result looks like

[image: looks like]

I am doing exactly the same in c++,

```
cv::convexHull(cv::Mat(contour), hull);
cv::drawContours(this->objectSegments[currentObject], cv::Mat(hull), -1, 255, -1);
```

but this is the resulting image:

[image]

(please look careful to see the `convexhull` points, this is not easily visible). I am getting only the points and not the filled polygon. I also tried using `fillPoly` like,

```
cv::fillPoly(this->objectSegments[currentObject],cv::Mat(hull),255);
```

but doesn't help. 
Please help me in fixing the issue. I am sure that i am missing something very trivial but couldn't spot it.

Comment: Please, show complete code. What's the type of variable `hull`. The problem is going to be with the way that parameter is structured -- it should be a vector of contours. It seems that in your case each point is interpreted as an individual contour.

Comment: @DanMašek Perfect!, your suggestion worked. I am using vector of vector points directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`drawContours()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#drawcontours) expects to receive a sequence of contours, each contour being a "vector of points".

The expression `cv::Mat(hull)` you use as a parameter returns the matrix in incorrect format, with each point being treated as a separate contour -- that's why you see only a few pixels.

According to the documentation of [`cv::Mat::Mat(const std::vector<_Tp>& vec)`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a23b182c4ffd46abe38f460c1480ae887) the vector passed into the constructor is used in the following manner:

> STL vector whose elements form the matrix. The matrix has a single column and the number of rows equal to the number of vector elements.

Considering this, you have two options:

- Transpose the matrix you've created (using [`cv::Mat::t()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a286d072cdb3d01e4171d0ff4dadb7d2c)
- Just use a vector of vectors of Points directly

The following sample shows how to use the vector directly:

```
cv::Mat output_image; // Work image

typedef std::vector<cv::Point> point_vector;
typedef std::vector<point_vector> contour_vector;

// Create with 1 "contour" for our convex hull
contour_vector hulls(1);

// Initialize the contour with the convex hull points
cv::convexHull(cv::Mat(contour), hulls[0]);

// And draw that single contour, filled
cv::drawContours(output_image, hulls, 0, 255, -1);
```