# drawContours does not fill / JAVA - OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv

Requiring the mighty help of stack overflow. I actually work on an app that has to analyze via OCR (I'm using tesseract) documents and extract all the text I can get out of it. Here is an example of the type of image:

[Image including text to extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts4R9.png)

Here is what I do on preprocessing to get rid of all the lines. In the future I would also probably have to analyze each "rectangle" separatly (feeding a zone defined by given lines to tesseract) so I guess there's simpler methods than this but i wouldn't have the "lines" coordinates.

```
package formRecog;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import static org.opencv.core.Core.bitwise_not;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;


public class testMat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

        Mat source  = Imgcodecs.imread("./image.png",Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR);
        Mat destination  = new Mat(source.rows(), source.cols(), source.type());
        Imgproc.cvtColor(source, destination, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);  
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("gray.jpg", destination);

        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(destination, destination, new Size(3, 3), 0, 0, Core.BORDER_DEFAULT);  

        Imgproc.Canny(destination, destination, 30, 90);
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("postcanny.jpg", destination);

        Mat houghlines = new Mat(); 
        Imgproc.HoughLinesP(destination, houghlines, 1, Math.PI / 180,  250, 185,5);

        //DESSINER LES LIGNES
        Mat result = new Mat(source.rows(), source.cols(), source.type());
        for (int i = 0; i < houghlines.rows(); i++) {
            double[] val = houghlines.get(i, 0);
            Imgproc.line(destination, new Point(val[0], val[1]), new Point(val[2], val[3]), new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 5);
            Imgproc.line(result, new Point(val[0], val[1]), new Point(val[2], val[3]), new Scalar(0, 0, 255),5);
        }

        Imgcodecs.imwrite("lines.jpg", result);

        Mat contourImg = new Mat(source.rows(), source.cols(), source.type());
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
        //Point offset = new Point();

        Imgproc.findContours(destination, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE );
        Imgproc.drawContours(contourImg, contours, -1, new Scalar(255, 0, 0),-1);

        Imgcodecs.imwrite("contour.jpg", contourImg);

        bitwise_not(destination,destination);


        Imgcodecs.imwrite("final.jpg", destination);

    }
}
```

Here is the final image

[Final image after processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsY3D.jpg)

Problem is, tesseract doesnt read anything on this :

11m ËEZË@ÜDS@
7
C@mpû@ 515 îf@5@??ûäû
©©m@@@ @@ vësw??a?
PF©@MÜGS @"@X@Ü©ÜÎÊQÜ©IÏÙ 1111
175515

Is the first "line" I get.

I think it is because the letters arent "filled" anymore and tesseract cannot read them, because tesseract actually gave me pretty good results precedently but the lines deleting method wasnt good.
I'd like to fill the letters with black but

Imgproc.drawContours(contourImg, contours, -1, new Scalar(255, 0, 0),-1);

doesnt do anything, although I'm pretty sure findContours worked fine cause if I imwrite the result of it I get the very same image as before.

I searched similar problemslike
[cv2.drawContours will not draw filled contour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45246036/cv2-drawcontours-will-not-draw-filled-contour)
and
[Contour shows dots rather than a curve when retrieving it from the list, but shows the curve otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311398/contour-shows-dots-rather-than-a-curve-when-retrieving-it-from-the-list-but-sho)
but didn't find anything I could use (maybe didn't get it).

Just so you know, I started programming courses like in september so I'm pretty new to the thing (forgive me if there's some gruesome things written here), but I don't have a choice on the subject I'm working on :)

I hope I made myself clear enough and my english isn't too bad.

My thanks.

EDIT: Thanks to Rick.M It's getting better, using CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE in findcontours and iterating via ldx in drawcontours did the trick. [New final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ittGC.jpg)

Is there a way to improve this result ? I'm guessing tesseract won't eat this aswell ?
thanks

Uploading postcanny image : [Image after canny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7yYs.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried to draw the contours using contourIdx instead of -1?

Comment: Do you mean by iterating contoursldx to draw each contour separatly ?
I just tried
for (int ldx = 0; ldx < contours.size(); ++ldx)
  Imgproc.drawContours(contourImg, contours, ldx, new Scalar(255, 0, 0),-1);
With no luck, but maybe I didnt get what you mean..

Comment: Yes I meant this. What does contours.size() say?

Comment: System.out.println(contours.size());
renders : 5369

Comment: and contourImg.type()?

Comment: according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167534/how-to-find-out-what-type-of-a-mat-object-is-with-mattype-in-opencv,
this a CV_8UC3 Mat

Comment: Try using `CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` instead.

Comment: For improving your result I would recommend using an unsharpmask/median filter before canny. Additionally, you can also try using CLAHE. Can you also upload the image after Canny? I could do this myself but unfortunately I don't have access to OpenCV atm. PS. Technically using the previous comment solved the question. Improving your result might require some work from you and another question.

Comment: Aknowledge, I will look into the filter and Clahe, thank you for your help and time, I'll just mark the thread as answered, if I find how :)

Comment: I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `drawContours` wasn't working as required was that the flag: [`CHAIN_APPROX_NONE`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) *stores absolutely all contour points*. Hence, using [`CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) which *compresses horizontal, vertical, and diagonal segments and leaves only their end points* gives you finished contours. In this case you could also use, `Imgproc.drawContours(contourImg, contours, -1, new Scalar(255, 0, 0),-1);` without the loop and should work fine.

Now, for the discussion in comments, the Canny image looks nice, but as you can see after zooming, the letters which aren't detected by `findContours` are not completely connected. I would suggest using [erosion](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html) with a small kernel (you have to play with the parameters) to get better results.